# Problems querying on KnowledgeArticle related objects

Tags: knowledge, relationships, articles

I'm trying to issue some SOQL which will return a KnowledgeArticle along with it's KnowledgeArticleVersion, ViewStats, and VoteStats. According to the [Knowledge data model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm) I should be able to do this because all three child objects with the data I need are decendants of KnowledgeArticle. This query should work but fails:

```
SELECT Id, ArticleNumber,
  (SELECT Id, Title FROM Knowledge_Base__kav),
  (SELECT Id, ParentId, NormalizedScore FROM VoteStats), 
  (SELECT Id, ParentId, NormalizedScore, ViewCount FROM ViewStats) 
FROM Knowledge_Base__ka LIMIT 1

## Error message ##
#
#  (SELECT Id, Title FROM Knowledge_Base__kav),
#                         ^
# ERROR at Row:2:Column:26
# Didn't understand relationship 'Knowledge_Base__kav' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
#
```

It works fine for ViewStats and VoteStats, but fails for KnowledgeArticleVersion. I ran a describe on the KnowledgeArticle object and I think the problem is related to the fact that `relationshipName` is set to null for the KnowledgeArticleVersion child.

```
// services/data/v29.0/sobjects/KnowledgeArticle/describe
"activateable": false,
    "childRelationships": [
        {
            "cascadeDelete": true,
            "childSObject": "KnowledgeArticleVersion",
            "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
            "field": "KnowledgeArticleId",
            "relationshipName": null,
            "restrictedDelete": false
        },
        {
            "cascadeDelete": true,
            "childSObject": "KnowledgeArticleViewStat",
            "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
            "field": "ParentId",
            "relationshipName": "ViewStats",
            "restrictedDelete": false
        },
        {
            "cascadeDelete": true,
            "childSObject": "KnowledgeArticleVoteStat",
            "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
            "field": "ParentId",
            "relationshipName": "VoteStats",
            "restrictedDelete": false
        }
    ]
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to correct this null relationship name? Alternatively, is there anyway to write a query which returns the desired results I mentioned above?

Comment: I remember (but can't find) a recent question about why some of these values are null. And I think the answer was that the describe call correctly reflects the situation that Salesforce have deliberately excluded that relationship in queries (e.g. because the underlying implementation makes it hard or expensive to do). I assume (but don't know) that you could use a second query to get the KnowledgeArticleVersion data.

Comment: Oh wow, that sucks but that seems like a move Salesforce would pull. I'm currently using the two query method but it's pretty slow. I was hoping to speed things up a bit by just issuing a single query.

Comment: Yeah some things feel pretty random. Occasionally there is an API you can use so you may yet get an answer from someone.